# Não consigo fazer git pull no servidor

Tags: git

Eu faço manutenção em um site. E nós sempre fazer o push das alterações e no terminal do servidor fazer um "git pull". Estava indo tudo bem até que dessa vez apareceu o seguinte erro.

```
error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

Alguém sabe porque esse erro acontece?

obervação: Por ser o servidor de produção, eu não posso fazer nenhum commit no repositório dele.

Comment: E você executou o git add pros arquivos modificados? Tem conflitos com outro branch ou com o remoto, não tem como sabermos.

Comment: o servidor de produção só é um clone do repositório "origin". Então eu só faço pull nele, pois ele tem alguns arquivos e diretório a mais que o git não deve rastrear. Então nunca fazemos um git add do lado do servidor.

Comment: Não falei que é feito do lado do servidor, você tem conflitos de arquivos, provavelmente devido a outro branch ou algo que fez com algum pullrequest ou com o remoto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este erro não tem qualquer relação com o servidor, até porque o erro ocorre num PULL ("puxar") e não PUSH ("empurrar"). Este é o primeiro indício, no GIT, de que o problema está na realidade do seu lado.

O primeiro passo para verificar qualquer problema com o seu repositório local é usar o `git status`. Este comando lhe indicará todos arquivos que foram alterados e ainda não foram comitados no seu repositório local.

Caso corra o comando `git status` e apareça qualquer arquivo como alterado você pode não conseguir fazer um `git pull` até desfazer as alterações ou comitá-las.

Para adicionar **TODAS** as alterações locais ao stage e comitá-las use os comandos `git add .` e `git commit -m "mensagem do commit"`.

Para "desfazer" as alterações de um arquivo específico você pode usar o comando `git checkout <arquivo>`.

Para desfazer **TODAS** as alterações locais **NÃO COMITADAS** você pode usar o comando `git reset --hard HEAD`.

Tenha em atenção que os dois últimos comandos são irreversíveis e qualquer alteração não comitada **SERÁ PERDIDA**.

No caso específico desta mensagem, o mais provável é que tenham ocorrido alterações no repositório remoto e no seu repositório local, você tenha feito um `git pull` anteriomente que gerou um conflito e este não foi resolvido. A mesma mensagem pode ainda aparecer em outras situações, mas, pelo descrito na pergunta, diria que esta é a mais provavel.

De toda forma, o `git status` indicará quais são os arquivos que estão com problemas. Corrija-os e os comite para poder fazer um novo `git pull`.

---

Para quem estiver curioso em como reproduzir o problema:

Cria um repositório e um commit com o arquivo `exemplo`

```bsh
mkdir repo
cd repo
git init
touch exemplo
git add exemplo
git commit -m "commit repo 1"
cd ..
```

Clona o repositório anterior e faz um commit alterando o arquivo de exemplo.

```bsh
git clone repo repo_clone
cd repo_clone
echo "alteração no repo_clone" >> exemplo
git add exemplo
git commit -m "commit clone 1"
cd ..
```

Volta ao repositório original e comita uma alteração no arquivo de exemplo

```bsh
cd repo
echo "alteração no repo" >> exemplo
git add exemplo
git commit -m "commit repo 2"
cd ..
```

Vai novamente ao repositório clonado e tenta fazer um `git pull`. Neste momento será apresentado o conflito.

```bsh
cd repo_clone
git pull origin master
```

Ignora o erro e volta para o repositório original, para fazer uma nova alteração.

```bsh
cd ../repo
echo "nova alteração no repo" >> exemplo
git add exemplo
git commit -m "commit repo 3"
cd ..
```

Vai novamente ao repositório clonado e faz um `git pull`. Neste momento será apresentada a mensagem de erro da pergunta.

```bsh
cd repo_clone
git pull
```

Para verificar o conflito no arquivo:

```bsh
cat exemplo
```

Será apresentado algo como:

```bsh
<<<<<<< HEAD
alteração no repo_clone
=======
alteração no repo
>>>>>>> (...)
```